# Unable to toggle a component for a second time using event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, elasticui

You can find the [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-input-controls-k1vzi).

I have a component that does the following:

1. Display an icon
2. If the icon is clicked, then, in its place, show a search input.
3. If the user clicks anywhere outside of the search input while it is showing, hide the search input and show the icon again instead.

The problem is that after you click the icon, the search input does show, and clicking anywhere outside of the search input shows the icon again. But if you click the icon again for a *second* time, the search input does not show.

I tried attaching a ref to the icon and evaluating if the event is contained when the icon is clicked, but that conditional statement did not help. How can I make sure that when I click on the icon for any additional times, that the input shows up again? Thanks!

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "@elastic/eui/dist/eui_theme_amsterdam_light.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { EuiButtonIcon, EuiFieldText } from "@elastic/eui";

const App = () => {
  const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);
  const searchInputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener(
      "click",
      (event) => handleClickOutside(event, showSearch),
      false
    );
  }, [showSearch]);

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      document.removeEventListener(
        "click",
        (event) => handleClickOutside(event, false),
        false
      );
    },
    []
  );

  const handleClickOutside = (event, showSearch) => {
    if (
      searchInputRef.current &&
      !searchInputRef.current.contains(event.target) &&
      showSearch
    ) {
      setShowSearch(false);
    }
  };

  if (showSearch) {
    return (
      <EuiFieldText
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Sample Search Placeholder ..."
        inputRef={searchInputRef}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <EuiButtonIcon
      aria-label="button"
      iconType="search"
      iconSize="xxl"
      onClick={() => setShowSearch(true)}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your approach was correct, all I changed were the `useEffect` functions.

I just removed the other `useEffect` function you used to remove the `click` event.

I also passed the `once` option to the event listener, so the event would be removed after being run once.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleClickOutside = () => document.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    if (searchInputRef.current?.contains(target) === false && showSearch === true) setShowSearch(false);
    else handleClickOutside();
  }, { once: true });

  handleClickOutside();
}, [showSearch]);
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: awesome thanks so much!!